# Removing a specific value in vector

Tags: c++, vector

I have encountered a list of errors when i was trying to execute this erase function to remove '2' from my vector. I am not sure where is the problem. Help will be greatly appreciated!

STRUCT MyInt

```
struct MyInt
{
friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &printout, const MyInt &Qn)
{
   printout<< Qn.value << endl;
   return printout;
}

  int value;
  MyInt (int value) : value (value) {}
};
```

STRUCT MyStuff

```
struct MyStuff
{
  std::vector<MyInt> values;

  MyStuff () : values ()
  { }
};
```

MAIN

```
int main()
{
MyStuff mystuff1,mystuff2;

for (int x = 0; x < 5; ++x)
    {
        mystuff2.values.push_back (MyInt (x));
    }

vector<MyInt>::iterator VITER;
mystuff2.values.push_back(10);
mystuff2.values.push_back(7);

    //error points to the line below
mystuff2.values.erase(std::remove(mystuff2.values.begin(), mystuff2.values.end(), 2), mystuff2.values.end());

    return 0;
```

}

Error Messages

> stl_algo.h: In Function '_OutputIterator std::remove_copy(_InputInputIterator, _InputIterator, const_Tp&) [with_InputIterator = __gnu_cxx:__normal_iterator > >, OutputIterator = __ gnu_cxx::__normal iterator > >, Tp = int]'
>
> No match for operator=='

Erorr messages showed the partciular line violated practically stl_algo.h's lines
Line 1267, 1190, 327, 1263, 208, 212, 216, 220, 228, 232, 236

Comment: "No match for operator==" What's unclear about it? You need to define an `operator==` function so you can compare `myInt` with integers.

Comment: @jrok, that should be an answer. It really is that simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to overload the `==` operator for class `MyInt`.

For example:

```
struct MyInt
{

friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &printout, const MyInt &Qn)
{
   printout<< Qn.value << endl;
   return printout;
}

// Overload the operator 
bool operator==(const MyInt& rhs) const
{
  return this->value == rhs.value;
}

  int value;
  MyInt (int value) : value (value) {}
};
```

Comment: That operator should be const.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Fixed it. What's the purpose of making it `const`?

Comment: So you could could compare two const MyInts.

Comment: @Michael: The same reason you made the argument const.  Do you know what `const` on the end of a member function signature means?

Comment: As a matter of fact it would be better to declare/define the comparison operator as a free function with the two arguments passed by constant reference. As it is, the operator is not symmetric: `MyInt(5) == 5` compiles, but `5 == MyInt(5)` will fail.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems. The error you're seeing is telling you that you haven't defined a equality comparison between int and your type. In your struct, you should define one equality operator

```
bool operator==(int other) const
{
    return value == other;
}
```

and of course define a global operator in the other direction:

```
bool operator==(int value1, const MyInt& value2)
{
    return value2 == value1;
}
```